# Asynchronous request multiple URLs, and most requests are timed out

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timeout

There are multiple URLs,I use asynchronous request to call the URLs,but most requests are timed out.The URLs are accessible,asynchronous request only any one of the URLs, can get a response.The code like this:

```
foreach (var url in URLs)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            IAsyncResult result = (IAsyncResult)request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RequestCallback), request);
            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), request, request.Timeout, true);
        }
```

Can someone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but if you have .net 4.5 and VS2012 you can use async await, which is much cleaner. The code would be...

```
var tasks = from url in URLs
            let request = WebRequest.Create(url)
            select request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
Stream[] results = Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

However this isn't a very good way to write code. You should process your streams as quickly as possible, as Windows should limit the number of Http streams your program can have open at the same time.

Comment: How to achieve "as quickly as possible"? I also have situation where I send hundreds of requests.